# ansible reuse variables defined on another host and another role

Tags: variables, ansible

I want to register a variable on a host and then reused in another host for a different role.

My main.yml

```
- hosts: icinga
  user: test

  tasks:
    - name: generetaing tickets for monitoring hosts
      command: /usr/sbin/icinga2 pki ticket --cn '{{ db01_hostname }}'
      register: pkidb01

    - set_fact:
        test: "{{ pkidb01 }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ pkidb01.stdout }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ test.stdout }}"

- hosts: dbserver02
  user: test

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ hostvars['icinga']['pkidb01']['stdout'] }}"        
    - debug: msg="{{ pkidb01 }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ hostvars['icinga'] }}"
```

The var pkidb01 is registered properly and I can access it with set_fact and also with the normal variable on the same host.
But on the next host  I can't access them in no way.

Output 1.host:

```
TASK [generetaing tickets for monitoring hosts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 23 February 2018  10:23:22 +0100 (0:00:09.593)       0:00:09.620 *******
changed: [10.10.10.100]

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 23 February 2018  10:23:23 +0100 (0:00:01.521)       0:00:11.142 *******
ok: [10.10.10.100]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 23 February 2018  10:23:23 +0100 (0:00:00.040)       0:00:11.182 *******
ok: [10.10.10.100] => {
    "msg": "08fcba18866e563dcded00e43637fec6dbb025e8"
}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 23 February 2018  10:23:24 +0100 (0:00:00.039)       0:00:11.222 *******
ok: [10.10.10.100] => {
    "msg": "08fcba18866e563dcded00e43637fec6dbb025e8"
}
```

Output 2.host:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 23 February 2018  10:23:33 +0100 (0:00:09.293)       0:00:20.558 *******
fatal: [10.10.10.30]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: \"hostvars['icinga']\" is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/main.yml': line 45, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - debug: msg=\"{{ hostvars['icinga']['pkidb01']['stdout'] }}\"\n      ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: \"hostvars['icinga']\" is undefined"}
```

Hostfile:

```
[dbserver01]
10.10.10.30

[icinga]
10.10.10.100
```

This solutions here didnt worked:
[Pass Ansible variables from one role (running on one host) to another role running on another host within the same playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368686/pass-ansible-variables-from-one-role-running-on-one-host-to-another-role-runni)

Comment: What is `icinga`? Host name or group name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood your question, your problem is that you didn't define your hostvar. You have to modify the [ansible-playbook in-memory inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html) with `add_host`:

```
- hosts: icinga
  user: test

  tasks:
    - name: generetaing tickets for monitoring hosts
      command: /usr/sbin/icinga2 pki ticket --cn '{{ db01_hostname }}'
      register: pkidb01

    - set_fact:
         test: "{{ pkidb01 }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ pkidb01.stdout }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ test.stdout }}"

    - name: "dummy HostVar"
      add_host:
        name: "myVar"
        value: "{{ pkidb01.stdout }}"


- hosts: dbserver02
  user: test

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ hostvars['myVar']['value'] }}"
```